# Given that a matrix represents an enlargement followed by a rotation, find the scale factor of the enlargement and the angle of the rotation.

Tags: matrices

The question is as follows:

The matrix **M** is defined by:

\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & -1 \\
  1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Given that **M** represents an enlargement followed by a rotation, find the scale factor
of the enlargement and the angle of the rotation.

Isn't there multiple different correct answers for this question?

According to this exam paper there is only one

Exam Paper Question 6(b)(i)
http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-QP-JUN12.PDF

Mark scheme Question 6(b)(i) http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-W-MS-JUN12.PDF

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, there are two answers: scale factor $c$ and rotation $\theta$, and scale $-c$ and rotation $\theta + \pi$. Perhaps "enlargement", in the language of this test, means that the scale factor must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

One has $\det(M)=2$, which implies that $M$ enlarges areas by a factor of $2$. The linear zoom factor is then $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore let us write $M$ as a product in the following form:
$$M=\left[\matrix{-{1\over\sqrt{2}} & -{1\over\sqrt{2}} \cr
{1\over\sqrt{2}}&-{1\over\sqrt{2}}\cr}\right]\>\left[\matrix{\sqrt{2} & 0 \cr
0&\sqrt{2}\cr}\right]\ .$$
We are told that the left hand factor here is a rotation $T$. The first column of $[T]$ gives $Te_1=\bigl(-{1\over\sqrt{2}}, \>{1\over\sqrt{2}}\bigr)$, whence $T$ rotates $e_1$ (and therewith the full plane) by $\theta={3\pi\over4}$.